# Averaging daily data over many years to replace NA values in R

Tags: r, time-series, average, replace, mean

I have a dataframe called daily which looks like this:

```
      daily[1:10,]
         Climate_Division    Date      Precipitation
      1                 1 1948-07-01     0.2100000
      2                 1 1948-07-02     0.7000000
      3                 1 1948-07-03     0.1900000
      4                 1 1948-07-04     0.1033333
      5                 1 1948-07-05     0.1982895
      6                 1 1948-07-06     0.1433333
      7                 1 1948-07-07            NA
      8                 1 1948-07-08            NA
      9                 1 1948-07-09            NA
      10                1 1948-07-10            NA
```

The objective that I would like to accomplish is average all the day values throughout the years (1948-1995) to replace the NA value that occurs on that particular day.  For example, since row 7 has an NA for July 7, 1948, I would average all the July 7 from 1948-1995 and replace that particular day with the average.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
 index <- which(is.na(daily$Precipitation)) # find where the NA's occur
 daily_avg <- daily # copy dataframe
 daily_avg$Date <- strftime(daily_avg$Date, format="2000-%m-%d") # Change the Date format to represent only the day and month and disregard year
 daily_avg <- aggregate(Precipitation~Date, FUN = mean, data = daily_avg, na.rm = TRUE) # find the mean precip per day 
 daily[index,3] <- daily_avg[daily_avg$Date %in% strftime(daily[index,2], format="2000-%m-%d"), 2]
```

The last line in the code is not working properly, I'm not sure why yet.  That is how my thought process of this problem is going.  However, I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it using a built in function that I am not aware of.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the data in your example, don't explain the problem. You should give  data for a certain day over many years with some NA values. For example, here I change the problem for 2 days over 3 years.

```
Climate_Division       Date Precipitation
1                1 1948-07-01     0.2100000
2                1 1948-07-02            NA
3                1 1949-07-01     0.1900000
4                1 1949-07-02     0.1033333
5                1 1950-07-01            NA
6                1 1950-07-02     0.1433333
```

The idea if I understand , is to replace NA values by the mean of the values over all years. You can use `ave` and `transform` to create the new column containing the mean, then replace the NA value with it.

```
daily$daymonth <- strftime(daily$Date, format="%m-%d") 
daily <- transform(daily, mp =ave(Precipitation,daymonth,
               FUN=function(x) mean(x,na.rm=TRUE) ))
transform(daily, Precipitation =ifelse(is.na(Precipitation),mp,Precipitation))


    Climate_Division       Date Precipitation daymonth        mp
1                1 1948-07-01     0.2100000    07-01 0.2000000
2                1 1948-07-02     0.1233333    07-02 0.1233333
3                1 1949-07-01     0.1900000    07-01 0.2000000
4                1 1949-07-02     0.1033333    07-02 0.1233333
5                1 1950-07-01     0.2000000    07-01 0.2000000
6                1 1950-07-02     0.1433333    07-02 0.1233333
```

Comment: @agstudy, my apologies for the not giving a well example.  You're method works perfectly!  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

Some dummy data

```
 set.seed(1)
 library(data.table)
 daily <- seq(as.Date('1948-01-01'),as.Date('1995-12-31')
 dd <- data.table(date = daily, precip = runif(length(daily)))
 # add na values
 nas <- sample(length(daily),300, FALSE)
 dd[, precip := {is.na(precip) <- nas; precip}]


 ## calculate the daily averages
 # add day and month
 dd[, c('month','day') := list(month(date), mday(date))]

 monthdate <- dd[, list(mprecip = mean(precip, na.rm = TRUE)),
                  keyby = list(month, date)]
 # set key for joining
  setkey(dd, month, date)
 # replace NA with day-month averages
 dd[monthdate, precip := ifelse(is.na(precip), mprecip, precip)]
 # set key to reorder to daily

 setkey(dd, date)
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly neater version of mnel's answer, which I would prefer to the accepted one:

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
# step 1: form data
daily <- seq(as.Date('1948-01-01'),as.Date('1995-12-31'),by="day")
dd <- data.table(date = daily, precip = runif(length(daily)))
# step 2: add NA values
nas <- sample(length(daily),300, FALSE)
dd[, precip := {is.na(precip) <- nas; precip}]
# step 3: replace NAs with day-of-month across years averages
dd[, c('month','day') := list(month(date), mday(date))]
dd[,precip:= ifelse(is.na(precip), mean(precip, na.rm=TRUE), precip), by=list(month,day)]
```